# How to deal with multiple entities using NSFetchedResultsController in swift

Tags: core-data, swift3

I have 3 similar tables that I would like to store in core data. I would like to view and edit the tables from a common view controller using NSFetchedResultsController. How can I generalize the setup or use sub-classing to achieve this? Foe example in my code show below

> Recommendation

is one of the entities. I have another entity named

> Results

which I would like to use (by changing the cell description in the table) and making the appropriate other changes.For example how can I represent Recommendation with a variable.

```
var moc:NSManagedObjectContext!
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Recommendation>!
var recommendations: [Recommendation] = []
```

and a method:

```
    func setupFetchedResultsController() {
    let dataRequest:NSFetchRequest<Recommendation> = Recommendation.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"recordNumber", ascending: true)
    dataRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: dataRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Recommendation.recordNumber), cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a base table view controller with properties to be overridden. I recommend to initialize the fetch controller lazily like suggested in the Core Data template.

```
class BaseTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext!

    // MARK: - Variables to be overridden

    var entity : String { fatalError("entity must be overridden") }
    var sortDescriptors : [NSSortDescriptor]? { return nil }
    var cacheName : String? { return nil }
    var sectionNameKeyPath : String? { return nil }
    var fetchPredicate : NSPredicate? {
        didSet {
            fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = fetchPredicate
        }
    }

   ...

    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: self.entity)
        fetchRequest.predicate = self.fetchPredicate

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = self.sortDescriptors
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                               managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!,
                                                               sectionNameKeyPath: self.sectionNameKeyPath,
                                                               cacheName: self.cacheName)
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        do {
            try aFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            self.present(error:error)
        }

        return aFetchedResultsController
    }()

   ...

}
```

Now you can subclass the controller

```
class RecommendationViewController: BaseTableViewController {

  // MARK: - Variables to overide

  override var entity : String { return "Recommendation" }
  override var sectionNameKeyPath : String? { return #keyPath(Recommendation.recordNumber) }
  override var sortDescriptors : [NSSortDescriptor]? { return [NSSortDescriptor(key:"recordNumber", ascending: true)] }
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. I need to fill the cell from the subclass so I created a function in the base class which I override. In the base class in cellForRowAt I have code as:         

let dataObject = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath);
        fillCell(cell: cell1, dataObject: dataObject);
        
When I override fillCell, what do I need to do cast dataObject to the entity so I can access the attributes? I need to mimic:
cell1.categorylabel.text = dataObject.category

Comment: I did figure it out. I cast it to my entity as 
let d = dataObject as! Recommendation
Then d exposes all the attributes.

Thank you for your help.